# How to create the API like this json data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Here is the API that i would like to create ,

```
{
    "Result": "PASS",
    "Device": [
        {
            "ID": "01",
            "State": "abc",
        },
        {
            "ID": "02"
            "State": "efg",

        },
    ]
}
```

i want to create the API by return to `ApiResult` model, Here is my controller,

```
[HttpGet("device")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ApiResult>> Device()
        {

            return new ApiResult();
        }
```

My Api Result Model

```
public class ApiResult
    {
        public string Result { get; set; }
        public ApiDevice[] Device { get; set; }
    }
```

Another model,

```
public class ApiDevice
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }

    }
```

The result that i get is like this,

```
{"result":null,"device":null}
```

How to get the result that i need like i mention in first paragraph?

Comment: Just to be clear a JavaScript object would not have a comma on the "last" element in an array, property in an object etc

Answer (score 0):

Your json is invalid, it should be:

```
{
    "Result": "PASS",
    "Device": [
        {
            "ID": "01",
            "State": "abc"
        },
        {
            "ID": "02",
            "State": "efg" 
        }
    ]
}
```

Your class should be something like:

```
public class Device
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string ApiResult { get; set; }
    public List<Device> Device { get; set; }
}
```

This site is great for transposing json to C#:  http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: this is incorrect. The JSON string is perfectly valid and while the comma does not need to be there, it doesn't actually make anything invalid.

Comment: Run it through a Json validator.

Comment: On jsonlint.com I get the following error: Error: Parse error on line 5:
...  "State": "abc",  },  {   "ID": "02"
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', got '}'

Answer (score 0):

In your example, when you return the new `ApiResult` from the controller, you are not initializing the properties `Result` or `Device` first. You will need to set both of those properties to the appropriate value before returning the object.

Since you are using an array in `ApiResult` object, you should probably require that values be passed in via the constructor to avoid resizing or replacing the array.

```
public class ApiResult
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public ApiDevice[] Device { get; set; }

    public ApiResult(string result, ApiDevice[] devices) {
        Result = result;
        Device = devices;
    }
}
```

Another option, which would get you the same JSON data from the API, is to use a List on the `ApiResult` object.

```
public class ApiResult
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public List<ApiDevice> Device { get; set; }

    public ApiResult() {
        Device = new List<ApiDevice>();
    }
}
```

My personal preference would be for the second option.